# Adding a custom "Add Custom Field" button to Custom Meta boxes

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

Did I use custom enough in the title?   Here is a quick explanation of what I am doing. I am creating a genealogy site and I have a custom post type called "Ancestor"  In this post type there is quite a bit of information that is going into custom fields.   To make it more user friendly, I've created [a few custom meta boxes to organize the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSURI.jpg)

None of the fields in those meta boxes need to be unique.  No one will have more than one birth date, etc.   But the next custom meta box I need to tackle is the "Parents / Siblings" box.  I don't want to create a meta box with 15 custom fields IDed as sibling1, sibling2...  I'd like to make use of the "Add Custom Field" button that lets you dynamically add additional custom fields. So people could add as many or as few sibling fields as they need.

I've created the meta boxes using the method at http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html

Any info or shove in the right direction to adding a "New Sibling Field" button would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [WP Alchemy Metabox](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/). What you are looking for is the [have_fields_and_multi](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#have_fields_and_multi).

Comment: Wonderful.  This was exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: WP alchemy Metabox is Great , saved me many times !